# Servicestack Swagger UI endpoint not behaving as expected with UseHttpsLinks

Tags: ssl, servicestack, swagger-ui

Using 4.0.31, my AppHost Configure method is declared like this:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
  HostConfig hc = new HostConfig() 
     { HandlerFactoryPath = "api", UseHttpsLinks = true };
  SetConfig(hc);
  Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
  Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());

  ...
}
```

I was under the impression that this would set the url for swagger-ui to be the https version of ../api/resources, however I'm still getting the regular http endpoint in the swagger URL textbox, like:

```
http://example.com/myapp/api/resources
```

Our web servers are behind load-balancers that perform SSL offloading (and require SSL), so the URL should be:

```
https://example.com/myapp/api/resources
```

On a positive note, using 'UseHttpsLinks' actually allows swagger-ui to function once you fix the endpoint url.  It didn't work at all without it!

I'm overriding the swagger url property using a replacement index.html via the [Virtual File System](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system) as a hack -- since in the development, QA, and staging environments, the url property is pointing to production...(not so good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config.UseHttpsLinks` has been expanded to also apply to the `BaseUrl` where it now changes `http://` urls to `https://` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b041b00e3ebf8c964ee66264063d2326a9c0305e).

This change is available from **v4.0.33+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  (One of these days I may actually ask a question you _haven't_ thought of already)